# How to call jquery function from another partial?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got a function `draw()` that is defined in the `_draw_foo.html.erb` partial.  That file contains all the required vars to do the drawing. The function normally runs on `window.onload`. I have another partial that updates the page and I'd like it to also run the draw function from here.  The associated jquery file is `_delete_bar.js.erb`.  Should I just give the button I use an id and then call something like:

```
$("#button').draw();
```

Can anyone help me

Comment: @silkfire, Yea, it doesn't work.  I was anticipating that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `draw` function exists on the page when it is loaded, and is still there after the page is modified, you can call it again the same way you did in page load (presumably with with `draw()`).

It's not clear where you got `$('button').draw()` from, could you explain that?

If you've tried this and it didn't work, run it with some kinda console to show js errors, [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will do this, for instance.

Comment: My thought on that was that calling `$("#button").draw()` would call the function when I pressed the button.  Do I just put `draw()` in the location that I want to call the function from?

Comment: If you want it to run the `draw()` function when `_delete_bar.js.erb` runs, then just add the `draw()` command to that js file.